# Implementing few excel functionality using JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, spreadsheet

I am trying to implement Summation function of MS EXCEL but not getting a way to get the values from the JTable cells. Can you suggest me some way to get the values from the cells and use it for my function?

Comment: `JTable` is not really suited to being a spread sheet component. The general consensus is that it would take more work to change it to be one, than to code a make a custom `SpreadSheetComponent` class.

Comment: i need to get the data inputed by the user on the GUI.....so can you suggest me how can i do that.

Comment: what have you tried? Note that this site isn't coding machine, nobody will it do _your_ work for you. Which starts by reading a decent tutorial to learn the basics ...

Comment: Hey that was rude of you...i tried using a MouseMotionListener but i was not able to do that so i thought this is where i will get my answers.

Answer (score 1):

For example, how can you get the value -

```
  String data[][] = {{"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"},{"Value4", "Value5", "Value6"},
  {"Value7", "Value8", "Value9"},{"Value10", "Value11", "Value12"}};

  String col[] = {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"};  

  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
  JTable table = new JTable(model);
  ...
  System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 2)); // row index and column index
  ...
```

it gives -

```
Value9
```

To get the values ​​from the table, you can implement the interface [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) in the anonymous inner class, for example -

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();

         int rowIndex = target.getSelectedRow();
         int columnIndex = target.getSelectedColumn();

        System.out.println(target.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex));
     }
});
```

See also:

- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Comment: (Copied from comment above) *"can you suggest me.."*  Why would I?  What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: you are correct about how to get data but i need to do that at runtime,so i wont be knowing the index of rows and column....so i am asking do i need to use any listener and if so tell me which

Comment: Thanks @Alexey i got the solution i need to use List Selection Listener